# The behavior of iBeacon detection when multiple beacons have the same IDs

Tags: android, ios, ibeacon, altbeacon

I'm involved in a business case where this will pop up as a question sooner or later, for deployment simplicity reasons:

For iOS, the integrated iBeacon support will be used. For Android, the AltBeacon library (by Radius) will be used.

Are there any fundamental problems and gotchas if all beacons for a given content/interaction, and in close proximity to each other, and possibly also overlapping, share the same UUID, Major ID and Minor ID?

They will all ping the same info, so in theory at least the app will just see a lot of pinging from seemingly the same device, unless somewhere in the system also MAC address will play a role to identify the source.

I'm thankful for any practical advice about this. We are potentially talking hundreds of beacons spread out in moving vehicles, with more than one per vehicle.

Regards,
Anders

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the typical best practice is to give each beacon a different unique identifier, there are some use cases where it is helpful to give multiple physical beacons the same identifier.  **Both iOS and Android will properly handle the case of multiple beacons in range with the same identifier,** but it is important to understand how it works:

- On **iOS CoreLocation**, **ranging callbacks will contain multiple beacon instances** in the `beacons` array with the same identifiers.  Internally, the OS keeps them distinct by Mac address, but there is no way to access this Mac or any other proxy for it using Core Location.  So while you can tell how many beacons are around and get rssi and distance estimates to each, you cannot tell which beacon is which.
- With the **Android Beacon Library**, by default **all beacons with the same identifier are combined into one**, with their RSSI measurements averaged and used to create a single distance estimate.  However, you can **configure it to behave the same way as iOS** by setting `Beacon.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true)`.   When you do, each beacon will be kept distinct by Mac address, and unlike iOS, you can also read the Mac with `beacon.getBluetoothAddress()`.

Comment: The point about iOS. Is it posible to scan for iBeacon and for BLE devices at the same time, and match the iBeacon with it corresponding BLE device by comparing its RSSI ?

Comment: You could try that, but it is hardly foolproof as two devices can have the same RSSI.

Comment: Thanks for the note about iOS. I set two beacons identical and placed them at different distances, and suddenly my app detected different proximities all the time. I now take a running (kind of) average (Math.floor((proximity + saved.proximity) / 2), with proximity levels converted to 1 - 3, so it only sees one beacon per ID. As I use the Cordova wrapper for this library I don't think I have access to the mentioned setting, nor "accuracy" on iOS. It behaves similar to the library.

Comment: @davidgyoung Thank you for the answer. Is it possible in iOS to simultaneously scan several beacons with the same MAC, but different UUID, major, minor? It seems like they are represented as one beacon, with changing identifiers over time.

Comment: @andrey, I have  observed the same.  iOS CoreLocation requires beacon MAC addresses to be distinct for simultaneous scanning.  You can accomplish what you describe with CoreBluetooth and a non-iBeacon type like AltBeacon or Eddystone.

Answer (score 1):

You should never have 2 beacons with the exact same values for UUID, Major and Minor. There are 2^128 possible UUIDs, 65,535 possible majors, and 65,535 possible minors. The probability any two beacons are the same should be basically zero.

If you need to identify a specific area with multiple beacons. Give them all the same UUID. Then perhaps you could make all the beacons on the same floor have the same major, and then vary the minors depending on the various touchpoints of the beacons.

Its fine if all the beacons are tied to the same data on your backend. This solution however gives you the option to set a different message for specific beacons later on if you wanted to. If you want to limit the web calls the phone makes after it encounters the first beacon that is fine too, you can just have different functionality after you have already encounter a beacon recently and not left the venue.

Without knowing your specific use case that is the best insight I can provide, but iBeacon protocol beacons should NEVER have all 3 values the same.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but it's hard to convince customers that don't even want to change from the default settings. My CMS allows for mapping multiple IDs to one site, so it's not a problem there.

Comment: I have numerous timers to secure that the CMS is only called when there's a stable transition between proximities.